# Get text box's scrollbar position

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, frameworks, scrollbar

I have a text box whose content is constantly changing and whenever that happens, the scrollbar automatically resets back to the top (not just the text box, another list view of mine behaves in the same manner). Is there anyway to save the current scroll position and then load it later? It's annoying to have to scroll the textbox/listview all the way down everytime the change occurs.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# WinForms" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior only occurs when you are using a normal TextBox with "multiline" set to true. If you use a RichTextBox instead, the scroll bar position will not change when new text is added.

Comment: No I want to scroll it to the position right before the update occurs, not at the end, so a user reading the text won't even know that the box's content was updated.

Comment: I am not sure I am clear on exactly what you are attempting to do. You could call this code before the update and after the udpate if you want.

Comment: I already tried that, but it just moved the scrollbar all the way to the bottom, which is not what I want. I just want the scrollbar to stay frozen unless the user moves it, and not by the update of the textbox itself.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't quite understand what he's doing, can you elaborate please (especially those focus things)? Will this work if what I'm using is a normal textbox, not a rich one?

Comment: @IcySnow, you should use a richtextbox for this. Calling the AppendText() method does not change the scroll position when new text is appended. Using a normal textbox with multiline set to to true will reset the scroll position when new text is added.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. BTW, is there something similar for a list view? Because the same thing happens when a list view updates its content (something like Windows Task Manager, since it doesn't move the scroll bar at all).